# Attribution for a "2nd generation" derivative work

Tags: derivative-works, attribution, cc-by-sa

How do you deal with attribution of a work that is derived from a work that is itself derived from an original work protected under CC BY-SA?

And while we're at it, let's push it further: Let's call the original work "**Work0**" and its author "**Author0**", the first derivative "**Work1**" and its author "**Author1**", and so on.

As **Author*N***, to whom should I give attribution? All the previous authors? Only the one before me, **AuthorN-1**? Or only the original **Author0**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a license requires attribution of the original authors/copyright holders when you create a derived work, then that means you need to give attribution to *all* copyright holders.

If Jane creates Work0, which is then adapted to Work1 by Alice, then the copyright of Work1 is **shared** between Jane and Alice.
This means that, if the work is under a CC-BY license and Bob uses Work1 to create a derived work Work2, then Bob needs to attribute both Alice and Jane.